# SQL Data Aggregation - Convert rows into columns - Table with billions of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have billions of rows in a table. Just pasting a sample data.

```
ticker     trade_date          trade_time     Price      Volume
---------------------------------------------------------------
AKS         01242017             1025           9.995    75038
AKS         01242017             1030          10        86891
AKS         01242017             1031           9.97     52815
AKS         01242017             1036          10.03     83556
AKS         01242017             1037          10.05     92644
```

I want to sum the data by trade hour.Usual NYSE hours of 0930 to 1600 hrs.

I want to see the above data as follows

```
ticker    tdate        1sthour       Avg Price        2nd hour   Avg price
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AKS        01242017     161929          9.99            229015     10.02
```

The challenge is I have 42000 different tickers and most tickers may not have data in each hour. In such cases I want 0 displayed for the hour in which there is no sale of stock. Tried case with sum but result does not look good.

Volume is calculated as follows 1st hor 930 - 1030=75038+86891=169129
Avg price=(75038*9.995+86891*10)/(75038+86891)

Comment: What database are you using?  What is the type of the columns?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want:

```
select ticker, tdate,
       sum(case when tradetime >= '0930' and tradetime <= '1030' then volume else 0 end) as volume_1,
       avg(case when tradetime >= '0930' and tradetime <= '1030' then price end) as price_1,
       sum(case when tradetime > '1030' and tradetime <= '1130' then volume else 0 end) as volume_2,
       avg(case when tradetime >= '1030' and tradetime <= '1130' then price end) as price_2,
       . . . 
from t
group by ticker, tdate ;
```

Comment: Gordon thanks a lot for your quick reply. The tradetime column is defined as varchar2 which is messing with my data.. That is my challenge

Comment: I am using oracle 12.c datatype is varchar2

Comment: Gordon thanks again. The sum seems to be working alright. Only average is messed up. Will work on it and post the answer if I find it. Thanks a ton for your simple and elegant code.

Comment: @user10588842 . . . The `avg()` should not have had the `else 0`.